# Force close when start GPS service

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a problem when the service is started: the appliaction shows a force close message.

my `startservice` in the main activity looks like this:

```
startService(new Intent(Main.this,GPSService.class));
```

GPSService.class

```
public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener {
LocationManager locationManager;
double x1,x2;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;

}
@Override 
public void onCreate()
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);   
}

public void  onLocationChanged(Location loc)
{
    x1=loc.getAltitude();
    x2=loc.getLatitude();
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String s){
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); 
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String s){
    //locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //x1=0;
   // x2=0;
}
 public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b){}
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: from where copy logcat??

Comment: did you added GPSService Activity in your menifest.xml file?

Comment: adb logcat in terminal or log window in eclipse if you use that.

Comment: @CApDroid yes  <service android:name="com.example.test.GPSService" android:enabled="true" >
        
        </service>

Comment: Without a log output from when the crash occurs, we can't help you.

Comment: @Dev We cannot help you without the stacktrace. Please put the stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to give following permissions in androidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES">
```